# How to drop a trigger in a resilient manner in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm looking to drop a currently in production trigger because it's no longer needed, but the problem is that when I try the simplest way, which is something like

```
drop trigger <triggername> on <tablename>
```

It caused a huge table lock and everything froze!

What the trigger does is:

When a row is inserted or updated, check for a field's contents, split it and populate another table.

How should I proceed to instantly disable (and dropping afterwards) without causing hassle in our production environment?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER` - but it requires the same strength of lock, so I don't think it'll do you much good.

There's work in PostgreSQL 9.4 to make `ALTER TABLE` take weaker locks for some operations. It might help with this.

In the mean time, I'd `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` to replace the trigger with a simple no-op function.

Then, to actually drop the trigger, I'd probably write a script that does:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE the_table IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
DROP TRIGGER ...;
COMMIT;
```

If anybody's using the table the script will abort at the `LOCK TABLE`.

I'd then run it in a loop until it succeeded.

If that didn't work (if the table is *always* busy) but if most transactions were really short, I might attempt a `LOCK TABLE` without `NOWAIT`, but set a short `statement_timeout`. So the script would be something like:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL statement_timeout = '5s';
LOCK TABLE the_table IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;
DROP TRIGGER ...;
COMMIT;
```

That ensures a fairly short disruption by failing if it can't complete the job in time. Again, I'd run it periodically until it succeeded.

If neither approach was effective - say, due to lots of long-running transactions - I'd probably just accept the need to lock it for a little while. I'd start the `drop trigger` then I'd `pg_terminate_backend` all concurrent transactions that held locks on the table so their connections dropped and their transactions terminated. That'd let the `drop trigger` proceed promptly, at the cost of greater disruption. You can only consider an approach like this if your apps are well-written so they'll just retry transactions on transient errors like connection drops.

Another possible approach is to disable (not drop) the trigger by modifying the system catalogs directly.

Comment: I think `NOWAIT` in your second SQL statement is a mistake.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for the complete answer! I will try this shortly but the information provided was great and contains ways to accomplish what I need! Awesome!

Comment: Just adding a note, I ran the query and it worked like a charm! Instant drop trigger completely resilient! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-altertable.html), since 9.5 `alter table ... disable trigger` now takes a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock, so that might be the way to go now.